# Keeping score across multiple Form windows

Tags: c#, windows, forms

I'm running a questionnaire with 10 questions. First Form.cs is just start button, to open first question in new Form.cs.

New form has 3 radio buttons, each of which should return different points (0, 5, 10). These points should accumulate across all forms, and a total should then be shown in the final Form.cs or uploaded to SQL etc.

I've tried to code it, but not sure its the best way.

```
namespace XX
{
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    int points;
    int totalscore = 0;

    private void btnCANCEL_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
    }

    private void zeropoint_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (zeropoint.Checked == true)
        {
            points = 0;
            totalscore = totalscore + points;
        }

    }

    private void fivepoint_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (fivepoint.Checked == true)
        {
            points = 5;
            totalscore = totalscore + points;
        }
    }

    private void tenpoint_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (tenpoint.Checked == true)
        {
            points = 10;
            totalscore = totalscore + points;
        }
    }

    Form3 thirdForm = new Form3();
    private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        this.Hide();
        var form3 = new Form3();
        form3.FormClosed += (s, args) => this.Close();
        form3.Show();

    }

}
```

Comment: Your post isn't clear on what the problem is or what you are asking.

Comment: You could pass the score to the constructor of each form

Comment: If you're trying to share changing information between forms, you might want to look into the C# delegate.

Answer (score 1):

I'd create a class that holds your score as a field. You would store a reference to an object of that class in your main form. When opening a new form you could pass the object reference along to that form. All changes to the score in that object would still be accessible through the reference in your main form after the separate forms have been closed.

Additionally if you find out that you need additional shared data you can simply add fields for that to the score class to have them accessible everywhere as well.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want a static member to keep track of your total score across all instances of your class. Look into this.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx#Anchor_0

And change your total count to

```
public static int totalcount = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You want a static class

```
static class Scoring
{
    public static int CurrentPoints { get; set; }
    public static int TotalScore { get; set; }

}
```

then to call it

```
Scoring.CurrentPoints += 10;
```